# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm getting this error when showing my user data. The weird part is that the data is shown anyway, but it glitches the heck of the app.

[see image right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icZIY.png)

Component

```
user:any

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, private alert: Ion_Alert) {
    if(this.auth.isLoggedIn) {
      this.user = this.auth.getUserData().subscribe({
        next: ( data:any ) => {
          this.user = data.data.person
          console.log(this.user)
        },
        error: error => {
          this.alert.showAlert("Error!", error.message)
          console.error('There was an error!', error)
        }
      })
    } else {
      this.alert.showAlert('Error!', "Either you're not logged in or you just haven't verified your email")
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<ion-content>
        <ion-card-content class="ion-text-center">
          <h1 *ngIf="user.first_name">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</h1>
          <h1 *ngIf="user.business_name">{{user.business_name}}</h1>
          <h3 *ngIf="user.documents_type.id === 1">DNI: {{user.dni}}</h3>
          <h3 *ngIf="user.documents_type.id === 2">NIT: {{user.nit}}</h3>
          <ion-text color="medium">
            <div style="display: flex;" class="ion-justify-content-center">
              <ion-icon name="location-outline" color="medium">
              </ion-icon>
              <p>{{user.municipio.name | titlecase}}, {{user.municipio.departamento.name}}, {{user.municipio.departamento.country.name}}.</p>
            </div>
          </ion-text>
          <h3>{{user.profession}} - {{user.phone}}</h3>
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

AuthService

```
getUserData() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.env.API_URL}/users/firebase/${JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).uid}`)
  }
get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return (user !== null && user.emailVerified !== false) ? true : false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html, add `?` here: `user.documents_type?.id`,

`user.documents_type` is probably undefined.

Comment: I just added a ? before every point on my document, and it worked xD Thanks man!!!